# Java HotSpot extremely long duration young collections

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is a long running server app which creates a lot of short lived garbage and almost nothing tenured after startup. Most of the time the young gen collection goes quickly, even with 10 gb it's fast since it's almost all garbage, but we are seeing occasional brutal outliers. As a potential hint, we are running a similarly configured server at lower load on a machine with more CPU resources but 12 gb less memory. We are not seeing this pattern there.

> java -Xms20g -Xmx20g -Xloggc:"./logs/gc.log" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseSpinning -XX:PreBlockSpin=1000 -XX:-UseCounterDecay -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m

Here is a snippet from the GC logs. Is it safe to say that it's spending the full time actually doing GC work (instead of waiting for threads to reach safepoints, for example) since sys time is high as well?

> 2013-12-13T14:04:50.388+0000: 56748.603: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10363808K->1248K(10421824K)] 10569323K->207003K(20907584K), 0.0035110 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T14:17:32.245+0000: 57510.460: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10363808K->1600K(10435072K)] 10569563K->207563K(20920832K), 0.0038460 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T14:29:08.572+0000: 58206.787: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10381824K->1408K(10430912K)] 10587787K->207875K(20916672K), 0.0045710 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T14:36:25.176+0000: 58643.391: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10381632K->1600K(10442432K)] 10588099K->208371K(20928192K), 0.0040800 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
>
> **2013-12-13T14:44:04.409+0000: 59102.624: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10397120K->1600K(10438848K)] 10603891K->208715K(20924608K), 14.7387710 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=143.05, real=14.74 secs]**
>
> 2013-12-13T14:52:50.287+0000: 59628.502: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10397120K->11488K(10446720K)] 10604235K->218819K(20932480K), 0.0127280 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
>
> **2013-12-13T14:59:34.934+0000: 60033.149: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10418208K->1536K(10445760K)] 10625539K->218931K(20931520K), 211.1968100 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=2067.08, real=211.16 secs]**
>
> 2013-12-13T15:12:04.478+0000: 60782.693: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10408256K->15136K(10448064K)] 10625651K->232723K(20933824K), 0.0147670 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.12, real=0.01 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T15:23:02.123+0000: 61440.338: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10426912K->12672K(10448768K)] 10644499K->232635K(20934528K), 0.0141040 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.12, real=0.02 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T15:31:09.119+0000: 61927.334: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10424448K->5280K(10452160K)] 10644411K->232907K(20937920K), 0.8134440 secs] [Times: user=1.22 sys=6.30, real=0.82 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T15:39:25.083+0000: 62423.298: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10421024K->6208K(10449344K)] 10648651K->235547K(20935104K), 0.0087890 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T15:47:52.781+0000: 62930.996: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10421952K->7200K(10456960K)] 10651291K->239123K(20942720K), 0.0094460 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
>
> 2013-12-13T15:58:18.594+0000: 63556.809: [GC [PSYoungGen: 10433248K->6752K(10454848K)] 10665171K->242331K(20940608K), 0.0091570 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]

Specs on the server above are dual 4-core X5570 with 48 gb of ram. HTOP is showing 15 gb used, the rest cached with the app using a little over 10 gb at any time (tenured is small). This makes me think it's not a paging issue

The other server I refer to is a dual 8-core E5-2690 with 32 gb of ram. Both are running jre 1.7.0_25 on fedora, although the server above is on a very old version

Answer (score 2):

Such high `sys` time is unusual. Could it be an **interference** with some other apps/activites on your system?

I think you should collect also other system stats - `vmstat`, `netstat`, `iostat`, `mpstat`, to rule out any interference or your GC time with activities on your system. Correlate those with the YounGen phases to see if there are any spikes during those long YounGen pauses.

Comment: The servers are dedicated to this app, it would be unlikely I think. Are you talking about CPU contention or something else? I've never seen much load on these boxes, I think it would be too much of a coincidence for that to happen from an outside app during a GC...

Comment: The usr time is 0.00 so it looks like its waiting on a system resource, not actually doing a GC work...

Comment: could you also try upgrading to jdk7u40 and monitor the GC with the Mission control?

Comment: Yes, might take a few days. I neglected to mention that we're running netsniff-ng bound to a CPU (-b 1) collecting all network traffic. The app is also reading from the same sockets and doing some processing work. It's probably averaging around 10 mb/s. Perhaps one of the app's threads happens to be on the netsniff CPU leading up to one of these long GC's; would waiting for that thread to reach a safepoint show up as `sys` time?

Comment: Perhaps try disabling the netsniff-ng if possible. If it blocks the JVM, it should show up in the vmstats/mpstat as perhaps increased/decreased number of context switches, etc. You can also start monitoring safepoints, there is a flag for that... but I am not sure about the perf. impact of that... because there is so many of them, it could be quite heavy.

Comment: Also, what are the interrupts on CPUs? any spikes/drops when netsniff kicks in? On which CPU is it? If its the same one as the GC threads? Perhaps you could bind CPUs for JVM and CPUs for netsniff so they do not influence each other... just to check if there is any interference.

Comment: Should have a less garbage intensive version to run on that box in the next week or so and will see if it persists (I presume it will). Then I will try binding threads away from netsniff's CPU. Netsniff is always running (averaging a few mb/s) although load is always pretty low on CPU